# How do I determine the current game version?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I want to know what is the current game version in **The Elder Scrolls Online**.

It would be best for me to be able to determine it in-game through emote-like commands, say `/ver`, but other choices are welcome too.

So far, I could determine only the **launcher**'s version through 'settings' > 'about', and it is '1.3.5.964404' at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I found a way. It seems it appears on the left bottom side of the screen when you launch the game to log in, and has more details in the tool tip.

So now I'm wondering if there are other ways to get the version information, through commands or API, perhaps.